# Escape values into database or after

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, escaping, xss

What is the right way to do escaping?

I have a basic registration form, username and password eg. I save these value to database via php script (everything is in php) using PDO so no SQL injection should be possible (i hope, if theres a safer way to do it, tell me please).
My question is, should I escape username value before saving it into database. So if someone would try to do

```
<script>alert("hi")</script>
```

it would save something like this

```
&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;hi&quot;)&lt;/script&gt;
```

in to the database. and after that no XSS should be possible (yeah kinda naive statement but I dont know how else to say this). Or save the plain text

```
<script>alert("hi")</script>
```

into database and at the time I want to print those values somewhere escape them?

In my opinion the safer way is to just escape on the save into database event, so put escaped values into database and then print them. But there is I guess my problem, should I again use escape function on those escaped values in database whenever I want to print them? Or just print them as they are (should be escaped). The first "solution" i dont like because the

```
<script>alert("hi")</script>
```

will be rendered in browser as escaped but not as  just with safe chars like `&lt;`
And the second solution seems that if I mess up once I'm doomed.

Comment: Enclose any code you have with backtick quotes.  The site provides help tools so you can properly learn how to ask and format questions before doing so, thus preventing community members from wasting their time having to decipher your question.

Answer (score 3):

Rule of thumb: if user is able to edit his input later, then save it in DB unescaped.

Otherwise escape before writing to DB to save processing step on every output.

Answer (score 0):

Always encode variables to the correct format. Storage in MySQL is (normally) plain text, so save it as plaintext, and not in HTML format.

- This lets you embed the text in other formats, e.g. JSON, plaintext emails or edit forms afterwards.
- You can consistently encode all plaintext to HTML in your templates. If you encode some text in advance, you get inconsistencies and may forget to encode some other texts.

Comment: MySQL offers the interface to store and retrieve strings, and you have strings, so just use it. HTML on the other hand requires you to escape plaintext in order to embed it.

Answer (score 0):

Please look into using [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements) which will pretect you from SQL injections.

Prepared statements act as a compiled template for SQL.  Using prepared statements prevents the database from ever interpreting data as a SQL query.

For example, if a user attempts to inject the following SQL:

```
DROP TABLE my_users;
```

The prepared statement will handle it as a string value and will not execute it as a SQL statement.

As for escaping HTML from input fields, if your input does not allow for HTML, you can strip out HTML from the string before saving it to the database using the [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/strip_tags) function.

```
$entered_username = '<script>alert("hi")</script>';
$entered_username = strip_tags($entered_username);
//Insert $entered_username into a prepared SQL statement to save to the database.
```

Either that, or implement a validation method on your input field that only allows for letters or numbers.

Comment: yeah, thats what i've meant with PDO, wasn't quite exact sorry.

Comment: yeah the regex with aplhanum characters came into my mind but then I realized what about other alphabets so I just wanna secure escaping, if you understand me